# SQL Server 2012 sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequences, sql-server-2012-express

I create a table and sequence in order to replace identity in the table I use SQL Server 2012 Express but I get this error while I tried to insert data to the table

> *Msg 11719, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
>   NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default objects, computed columns,
>   views, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, user-defined
>   table types, sub-queries, common table expressions, or derived
>   tables.*

T-SQL code:

```
insert into Job_Update_Log(log_id, update_reason, jobid) 
values((select next value for Job_Log_Update_SEQ),'grammer fixing',39);
```

This is my table:

```
create table Job_Update_Log
(
   log_id int primary key  ,
   update_reason nvarchar(100) ,
   update_date date default getdate(),
   jobid bigint not null,
   foreign key(jobid) references jobslist(jobid)
);
```

and this is my sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Job_Log_Update_SEQ] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 NO CACHE 
GO
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just get rid of the subselect in the VALUES section, like this:

```
insert into Job_Update_Log(log_id,update_reason,jobid) 
        values (next value for Job_Log_Update_SEQ,'grammer fixing',39);
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272694%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Your insert syntax appears to be wrong. You are attempting to use a `SELECT` statement inside of the `VALUES` section of your query. If you want to use `SELECT` then you will use:

```
insert into Job_Update_Log(log_id,update_reason,jobid) 
select next value for Job_Log_Update_SEQ,'grammer fixing',39;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b614e/2)

I changed the syntax from `INSERT INTO VALUES` to `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. I used this because you are selecting the next value of the sequence.

However, if you want to use the `INSERT INTO.. VALUES`, you will have to remove the `SELECT` from the query:

```
insert into Job_Update_Log(log_id,update_reason,jobid) 
values(next value for Job_Log_Update_SEQ,'grammer fixing',39);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98590/2)

Both of these will `INSERT` the record into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

---

–With a table

create sequence idsequence
start with 1 increment by 3

```
create table Products_ext
(
id int,
Name varchar(50)
);

INSERT dbo.Products_ext (Id, Name)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.idsequence, ‘ProductItem’);

select * from Products_ext;


/* If you run the above statement two types, you will get the following:-

1    ProductItem
4    ProductItem

*/

drop table Products_ext;
drop sequence idsequence;

------------------------------
```